# How to hide the private variable with [SerializeField] inherit from the base class in the Inspector in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inspector

When I have a `private` variable `id`, I write `[SerializeField]`before i define it:

```
class A{
   [SerializeField]
   private int id;
}
```

And, I have another class

```
Class B : A{
}
```

When I add the component `B` on one object, I can see variable `id` in the inspector, How can I hide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the only way is to build a custom inspector:
http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/editor/building-custom-inspector

Comment: Woo~ It looks fantastic. Last month, I study `AssetBundles`, i found i can change the editor, It is new to me.Now I find I can change the inspector. Unity really surprise me.

Comment: could I please get Best answer then?

Comment: Sure, but i dont know how to choose your answer to be the best. Just Accept?

Comment: click the 'tick' icon on the left hand side.

Comment: Have you tried to make your custom-inspector? I have many class, so I must create many editor script? It is so sad.

Answer (score 2):

Writing a custom inspector is fine, but often tedious if the only thing you need to change is a visibility of a serialized field.

Try [[HideInInspector]](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HideInInspector.html) attribute before a serialized fields. It will be serialized but not shown in the inspector.

---

EDIT

Here's a couple of reference to understand serialization: [ref1](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2012/10/25/unity-serialization/), [ref2](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ISerializationCallbackReceiver.OnBeforeSerialize.html).

I'll try to explain in brief:

> The process of setting the fields of your objects, and getting them,
>   is called deserialization and serialization respectively. Unity's
>   serializer is able to serialize many different kinds of fields, but
>   not all of them.

In a few words:

**Serialization**

Is the term used to indicate every data flow from the runtime memory to outside (such inspectors, files on the disk, ...)

**Serialization**

Is the term used to indicate every data flow towards the runtime memory to outside (es. change a value in the inspector and the serializer thread will deserialize it into the runtime memory).

The main point is that there are situations where you want a given field to be serialized (es. saved into a prefab on disk) but don't want to show it in the inspector.
If this is the case, rewriting a whole inspector is an overkill. Use instead `[HideInInspector]` attribute.

If you want it not to be serialized nor shown in the inspector, just let it private without `[SerializedField]`  or public and mark it as[[NonSerialized]](http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/NonSerialized.html).

Comment: what's the different between serialized and shown in the inspector?